# Cannot import passwords into Opera

Tags: windows, google-chrome, opera

I'm trying to import my passwords from Chrome into Opera but it's not working, it shows that all settings were imported successfully even though the passwords aren't there (bookmarks are).

I've also tried to install Firefox, import the passwords from Chrome in there, and then import the passwords from Firefox into Opera but that didn't work either.

I've tried deleting the profile in c:\User... directory and tried again but that didn't help.

Any idea how to get it working?

Spec: Opera 45 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you export Opera/Chrome passwords to a XML file and then import passwords from a XML file to Opera/Chrome.

You can find such an utility [here](http://www.pepak.net/files/tools/chromepass-0.02.zip) and [it's source](http://www.pepak.net/files/tools/chromepass-0.02-source.zip).